# php-fpm with Magento throwing random Fatal Errors

Tags: magento, nginx, php

I have a CentOS6 server with nginx / php-fpm running Magento. Everything was fine for months until recently when random Fatal Errors will popup.  It happens in Magento's admin, in the store, and everywhere.  It doesn't happen often, but it does happen.

Some of the errors it will throw:

> Fatal error: Cannot override final method Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::clearInstance()
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Category' not found
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function setStoreId() on a non-object
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getTable() on a non-object

Once the error throws, you can't get past it.  The only way workaround is to restart php-fpm.

I've read things about APC causing problems, but I haven't had success trying those solutions.

The server has 2GB of RAM and the phpinfo is located here:
http://already2harvest.com/php.php

Any gurus have any good ideas I can pursue?

Comment: I don't know what is reason, but you could try to turn off "System/Tools/Compilation" if you used it.

Comment: Compilation has always been off. I know it's something to do with php-fpm but I don't know what...

Comment: Did you ever actually resolve this issue? Occasionally getting similar symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this question.  But I'll respond anyway.

It seems to be APC that's the culprit .  I'm experiencing the exact same issue.  If I turn off APC, no more errors.  But, of course, that means the performance goes back to being terrible.